# Keras mnist tutorial giving me very low accuracy

Tags: python, keras

I am trying out the mnist tutorial using keras at https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py but am getting really low accuracy. I got a test accuracy of 83% on my 1st trial after 12 epochs and 75% on my 2nd trial. The page claims that it is able to get 99.25% test accuracy after 12 epochs. I am not sure why this is happening because I literally copy pasted the code into PyCharm.

I am using Keras version 2.0.0 with Tensorflow version 0.12.1 as its backend. Training is done via CPU.

Could the reason be due to the version? Should I upgrade to the latest versions of Keras and Tensorflow? I hope someone can run the exact code and let me know of their results after 12 epochs with the Keras and Tensorflow version.

Or could the reason be due to the variability in deep learning and that I might eventually get a ~99% test accuracy after 12 epochs if I run enough simulations. This is the code in case anyone doesn't wanna get into the link

```
'''Trains a simple convnet on the MNIST dataset.
Gets to 99.25% test accuracy after 12 epochs
(there is still a lot of margin for parameter tuning).
16 seconds per epoch on a GRID K520 GPU.
'''

from __future__ import print_function
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import backend as K

batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
epochs = 12

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

# the data, shuffled and split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove the dropout for a training run? What are your results then?

Comment: If I were you I would preprocess and normalize the data. Also what kind of initialization of the weights are you using ? Usually with ReLU activation functions, He Initialization is the way to go https://keras.io/initializers/

Comment: @petezurich I just completed the training without any dropouts and the test accuracy deterioriates to 0.2136

Comment: @Nathan thanks I will try the HE initializer.  Do either of you have keras and is willing to run the code in the link ? I'd like to know if the disparity is due to version or something else..

I don't feel safe starting on my school project if I can't even get the tutorials working..

Comment: I've created a new environment with anaconda, installed `keras==2.0.0` and `tensorflow==0.12.1`, and got `val_acc: 0.9753` already after the first epoch.

Comment: Can you check whether you're using the correct MNIST dataset?
 `keras.datasets.mnist` does not re-download the file if it already exists under your home directory. My `~/.keras/datasets/mnist.npz` has a MD5 sum = `8a61469f7ea1b51cbae51d4f78837e45`.

Comment: @Yu-Yang i have verified the MD5 sum of my mnist.npz file and its the same as yours. I even deleted and re-downloaded the dataset and still get very low accuracy. What a weird issue... I am just going to try and upgrade to the later versions and see what else I can do..